# Omnichannel Inventory & B2B Commerce. How to update the reservation count in Omnichannel Inventory once the reservation made from experience site

Tags: rest-api, lightning-experience, digital-experience, b2b-commerce

Can somebody help to have more idea on how the values for the terms Available to fulfill (ATF), Available to order (ATO), Future inventory, Quantity on hand, Quantity reserved, Reservation, Safety stock count in Salesforce Omnichannel Inventory get updated. I am using Omnichannel Inventory Connect REST APIs to Get Availability Records ( /commerce/oci/availability/availability-records/actions/get-availability ). But the response shows as below :

{
"errors": [],
"locationGroups": [],
"locations": [
{
"inventoryRecords": [
{
"availableToFulfill": 0.0,
"availableToOrder": 0.0,
"futures": [],
"onHand": 0.0,
"reserved": 0.0,
"safetyStockCount": 0.0,
"stockKeepingUnit": "DL516"
},
{
"availableToFulfill": 0.0,
"availableToOrder": 0.0,
"futures": [],
"onHand": 0.0,
"reserved": 0.0,
"safetyStockCount": 0.0,
"stockKeepingUnit": "PV508"
}
],
"locationIdentifier": "Warehouse"
}
],
"success": true
}

I would like to know how these values get updated/populated and also how its reflected in B2B Commerce Experience Site to show the stock availability/out of stock. And once order is placed from experience site how the reservation count is passed to Omni Channel Inventory.
Kindly share any documentation related to how to integrate Omnichannel Inventory and Salesforce B2B Commerce.

Regards

Note : I have used below salesforce help document to get the API's

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inv_omnichannel_inventory_connect_rest_apis.htm&type=5https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inv_omnichannel_inventory_connect_rest_apis.htm&type=5